# Socket.io broadcast stops working if user leaves namespace then rejoins

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

My situation is this:

1. **User A** creates namespace with name of his choice
2. **User B** joins created namespace
3. **User A** sends message which is broadcasted by the server and received by **User B**
4. **User B** sends message which is broadcasted by the server and received by **User A**
5. **User B** leaves namespace through *client-side socket.disconnect();*
6. **User B** rejoins namespace
7. **User B** sends message which is broadcasted by the server and IS received by **User A**
8. **User A** sends message which is broadcasted by the server and NOT received by **User B**

Important Notes:

- If **User B** refreshes the page and rejoins that namespace while **User A** remains there, he can
  then send and receive messages normally again.
- When **User B** is in the '*not working*' state, he still seems to be getting events through socket emit. In other words, only **User A** receives events initiated by both parties, where **User B** only receives events initiated by himself.

Why, when **User B** leaves and rejoins does the server become a one way street relative to him?

Server Code:

```
var app = require('express')()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(8080);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

var connection_function = function(socket) {
    socket.on('join_chat', function(data) {
        socket.set('fb_id', data.id);
        socket.emit('joined_chat', data);
        socket.broadcast.emit('joined_chat', data);
        socket.namespace.connected_users[data.id] = data;
    });
    socket.on('send_message', function(data) {
        data.user = socket.namespace.connected_users[socket.store.data.fb_id];
        socket.emit('recieve_msg', data);
        socket.broadcast.emit('recieve_msg', data);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        socket.broadcast.emit('left_chat', socket.namespace.connected_users[socket.store.data.fb_id]);
        delete socket.namespace.connected_users[socket.store.data.fb_id];
    });

}
var chats = {};

var main = io.of('/main');
main.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('new_chat', function(data, fn) {
        if(!chats.hasOwnProperty(data.chat_name)) {
            chats[data.chat_name] = io.of('/' + data.chat_name);
            chats[data.chat_name].on('connection', connection_function);
            chats[data.chat_name].connected_users = {};
        }
        fn(data);
    });
});
```

**Update (Friday October 12, 2012)**

After some  more research it appears that the issue may be with socket.io:

https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/issues/251

https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/issues/473

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't want to be using socket.io rooms instead?

socket.join(roomName);

io.socket.in(roomName).emit(.....;

I have a working example of rooms here: https://github.com/rcpeters/openMap_me/blob/master/app.js

Comment: hum, well your example looks like you re trying to do to much. This: "socket.namespace.connected_users[data.id] = data;"  looks wrong to me. I would simplify your code following the namespace example here: http://socket.io/#how-to-use

Comment: Eh, Thanks for trying. I'll put a bounty on it in a couple days if I don't resolve the issue then.

Comment: Appears the problem is with socket.io